# Continuity of partial derivative notation

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Given a function $f(x,y):X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where  $X\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and $Y \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. Let say I want to impose additional regularity.

**Assume:** 
$f(x,y) \in L^2(X\times Y)$, is continuous in $y$, and $\nabla_y f(x,y)$ is continuous in $y$. Where $\nabla_y$ denotes gradient with respect to $y$.

A more natural assumption that encompasses this is:

**Assume:** 
$f(x,y) \in L^2(X\times Y)\cap C^1(\overline{X\times Y})$.

Is there any notation to represent the first assumption? For example, there are Sobolev spaces like $g(t,x) \in C([0,T],L^2(X))$ etc, where continuity is assumed in time; however, $t$ seems to always be a scalar, can it be used with $t \in \mathbb{R^2}$ for example?

I realize it is somewhat odd, however, there is no need to assume all partials exist and are continuous.

Comment: Such things are rather common in Calculus of Variations, but I've never seen a short piece of notation. In my experience, books and papers introduce these assumptions "by words", as you did.